# How do I make p2pool accessible from outside my network?

Tags: mining-pools, p2pool

I want my pool to be accessible from the public, i have forwarded port 9332 and 9333 on both udp/tcp, and its still not possible, and the system firewall is open for that, for example i cant access the pool stats through http://external_WAN_IP:9332 but i haven't yet tested using a miner and connect it to the pool.

i have set up the pool according to the instructions here http://p2pool.in with the latest version 14.0

Comment: Two questions: 1) Is P2Pool listening on a non-local port? 2) Is the port open when you use a [port checker](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)?

Comment: the p2pool is listening on a local port, the port is open, i have checkedit several times.

Comment: Let me clarify: Is it listening on 127.0.0.1, or on an IP address accessible to your network?

Comment: its listening on 127.0.0.1, im running it on the same computer as the miners and bitcoin core

Comment: That's not going to work. It needs to listen on 0.0.0.0, or the IP address assigned to you by your DHCP server.

Comment: is there a command to specify the address, and how is it goin to work without it being connected to bitcoin core.